# Is any geometry also a Klein geometry?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Can any metrical or axiomatic geometry be shown to be isomorphic to a Klein geometry?
Can any manifold with a (pseudo) Riemannian metric be defined in the Kleinian sense?

Comment: Usually the definition of a Klein geometry requires local homogeneity, so clearly not.

Comment: The answer will depend on precisely how constrained your notion of "metrical or axiomatic geometry" is.  You could tautologically define things in a way where the answer is yes, I suppose.  But you probably won't get agreement on that being the class of "metrical or axiomatic geometry".

Comment: [Here](https://www.imsc.res.in/~kapil/papers/krp.pdf) is a kind of answer for dimension at least 3. The case of dimension 2 assuming Desargues' axiom was answered positively by Blaschke. The reference to Blaschke can be found in Sharpe's book.

Comment: The answer might also depend on the meaning of "any" ("is every geometry also..." vs. "is some geometry also..."). Many times it is best to avoid the "any" quantifier.